# Managing cookies with Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, prototype

I have tried to create a popup manager using Javascript, the idea is to display the ajax popup only once. For some reason the popup appears more than once and randomly. I would like to know if there is something wrong with my code:

```
 function SetCookie(name, value, days) {
     var expire = new Date ();
     expire.setTime (expire.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * days);
     document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + "; expires=" +expire.toGMTString();
 }
 function GetCookie(name) {
   var startIndex = document.cookie.indexOf(name);
  if (startIndex != -1) {
      var endIndex = document.cookie.indexOf(";", startIndex);
      if (endIndex == -1) endIndex = document.cookie.length;
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(startIndex+name.length+1, endIndex));
  }
  else {
      return null;
  }
 }

function DeleteCookie(name) {
    var expire = new Date ();
    expire.setTime (expire.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    document.cookie = name + "=; expires=" + expire.toGMTString();
}

 function Pop() {
    var cookie = GetCookie("popup");
    if(cookie==null) {
        SetCookie("popup",1,300);
 }
    else {
        if(cookie==1) {
            new Ajx.Dialog();
            SetCookie("popup",2,300);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
  window.onload = Pop;
```

Comment: Based on the code you provided you don't appear to have defined a `SetCookie` function.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so what is happening is this:

```
function Pop() {
    var cookie = GetCookie("popup");
    if(cookie==null) {
        SetCookie("popup",1,300);
    }
    else {
        if(cookie==1) { 
            new Ajx.Dialog();
            SetCookie("popup",2,300);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

1. First visit and cookie is null. Cookie is set to `1` and `pop` function exits.
2. Second visit and cookie is `1`. `Ajx.Dialog` called, cookie set to `2`, `pop` function returns false.
3. Third visit and cookie is `2`. `pop` function returns false.

Is this what you intended?

**UPDATE:**

I'm not sure what you want to happen, but if you want the popup to fire once on first visit then use the following:

```
function Pop() {
    var cookie = GetCookie("popup");
    if(cookie != 1) {
        new Ajx.Dialog();
        SetCookie("popup", 1, 300);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes my idea is to display the popup only on the second pageview

Comment: OK. I found your `pop` function worked as you expected on Firefox 3.6 and see no reason why it wouldn't work on other browsers.